# Как через ffmpeg получить с микрофона звук, усилить его и отправить на виртуальный кабель?

Tags: windows, winapi, аудио, ffmpeg, directshow

Вот список устройств.

```
[dshow @ 0000000002ca9360] DirectShow audio devices
[dshow @ 0000000002ca9360]  "╨Ь╨╕╨║╤А╨╛╤Д╨╛╨╜ (Realtek High Definition Audio)"
[dshow @ 0000000002ca9360]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{B9E6CC62-9748-42D0-B8CF-9E27BB53D9C3}"
[dshow @ 0000000002ca9360]  "CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)"
[dshow @ 0000000002ca9360]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{BA3025B3-E880-46D4-AEE7-CE59718D816B}"
```

Нужно, чтобы звук из первого микрофона усиливался в 2 раза и передавался в виртуальный кабель два. Мой код не работает, говорит:

```
Requested output format 'dshow' is not a suitable output format
audio=CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable): Invalid argument
```

Сам код:

```
ffmpeg -re -f dshow -i audio="@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{B9E6CC62-9748-42D0-B8CF-9E27BB53D9C3}" -af 'volume=2' -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le -f dshow audio="CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)"
```

Comment: А что говорит: "ffmpeg -sinks dshow"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dshow` не поддерживается как output устройство. Так что, пока - никак.

На дефолтный выход можно выводить при помощи `sdl` формата. Либо посмотреть, что вам доступно, вызвав

```
ffmpeg -devices
```

Comment: @darthvlado, какой вариант помог? sdl?

Comment: Никакой, решил проблему покупкой другого микрофона. Просто вспомнил, что ответ нужно бы пометить.

Comment: Тогда лучше написать свой ответ и отметить его как решением, а то может путаницу потом людям создать.